# Control.OnPaint() is called twice in a Custom Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am new to Custom Controls. I'm trying to create a flat `Button` which changes its border color and text color when the Mouse or the Keyboard focus comes to it.

When I change the `BorderColor` Property of the `Button` from the Designer, it doesn't update the color and also when I run the program, `BorderColor` remains the same.

I am not sure about the `OnPaint()` event code I have written. It consoles out twice when run first time. I don't know why!

How to make a Custom Control so its attributes can be fiddled in Designer?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mato
{
    class FlatButton : Control
    {
        public override Cursor Cursor { get; set; } = Cursors.Hand;
        public float BorderThickness { get; set; } = 2;
        public Color BorderColor { get; set; } = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0047A0");
        public Color TextColor { get; set; } = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0047A0");
        public Color ActiveBorderColor { get; set; } = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#158C3F");
        public Color ActiveTextColor { get; set; } = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#158C3F");

        private SolidBrush borderBrush, textBrush;
        private Rectangle borderRectangle;
        private bool active = false;
        private StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();

        public FlatButton()
        {
            borderBrush = new SolidBrush(BorderColor);
            textBrush = new SolidBrush(TextColor);

            stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Console.WriteLine(textBrush.Color.ToString());
            borderRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(borderBrush, BorderThickness), borderRectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, (active) ? textBrush : borderBrush, borderRectangle, stringFormat);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBrush.Color = ActiveTextColor;
            this.Refresh();
            active = true;
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBrush.Color = TextColor;
            this.Refresh();
            active = false;
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
        }

        protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Focused");
            borderBrush.Color = ActiveBorderColor;
            textBrush.Color = ActiveTextColor;
            this.Refresh();
            active = true;
            base.OnGotFocus(e);
        }

        protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            borderBrush.Color = BorderColor;
            textBrush.Color = TextColor;
            this.Refresh();
            active = false;
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The mouse and focus events don't fire in the designer.  Your BorderColor and TextColor properties needs a setter that calls this.Invalidate().

Comment: sorry @HansPassant i din't get your point about setter function... why onpaint is fired twice any idea?

Comment: Probably because the Size changed, you didn't post enough code to make the call.  It will fire more times, focus on the real problem.  When the colors you use in OnPaint change then you have to repaint.  That's what Invalidate() does.

Answer (score 1):

I slightly modified your original class, adding some private fields that keep track of the current status of your Button control.

Substituted: `OnGotFocus()` and `OnLostFocus()` with [`OnEnter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enter?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Enter);k(System.Windows.Forms.Form);k(VS.Properties);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(System.Windows.Forms.Form);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`OnLeave()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Added some private fields that reference the current Color of Text and Border, when those are modified on a Button Click() event and when the Control is entered or when the input focus leaves.

**`private Color m_CurrentBorderColor;`**
**`private Color m_CurrentTextColor;`**

Also, each time a property is changed, the `Invalidate()` method is called, which raises the [OnPaint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Paint);k(System.Windows.Forms.Form);k(VS.Properties);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(System.Windows.Forms.Form);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) event of the Control, updating its aspect.

Other minor changes.

```
class FlatButton : Control
{
    private Color m_TextColor;
    private Color m_BorderColor;
    private Color m_ActiveBorderColor;
    private Color m_ActiveTextColor;
    private Color m_CurrentBorderColor;
    private Color m_CurrentTextColor;

    public override Cursor Cursor { get; set; } = Cursors.Hand;
    public float BorderThickness { get; set; } = 2;
    public Color BorderColor {
        get => this.m_BorderColor;
        set { this.m_BorderColor = value;
              this.m_CurrentBorderColor = value;
              this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public Color TextColor {
        get => this.m_TextColor;
        set {
            this.m_TextColor = value;
            this.m_CurrentTextColor = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public Color ActiveBorderColor { get => this.m_ActiveBorderColor; set { this.m_ActiveBorderColor = value; } }
    public Color ActiveTextColor { get => this.m_ActiveTextColor; set { this.m_ActiveTextColor = value; } }

    private StringFormat stringFormat;

    public FlatButton()
    {
        this.m_TextColor =  ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0047A0");
        this.m_BorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0047A0");
        this.m_ActiveBorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#158C3F");
        this.m_ActiveTextColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#158C3F");
        this.m_CurrentTextColor = this.m_TextColor;
        this.m_CurrentBorderColor = this.m_BorderColor;

        stringFormat = new StringFormat()
        {
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        };
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (SolidBrush textBrush = new SolidBrush(this.m_CurrentTextColor))
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(this.m_CurrentBorderColor, this.BorderThickness))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, e.ClipRectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, textBrush, e.ClipRectangle, stringFormat);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        this.m_CurrentTextColor = this.m_ActiveTextColor;
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        this.m_CurrentTextColor = this.m_TextColor;
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEnter(e);
        this.m_CurrentBorderColor = this.m_ActiveBorderColor;
        this.m_CurrentTextColor = this.m_ActiveTextColor;
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLeave(e);
        this.m_CurrentBorderColor = this.m_TextColor;
        this.m_CurrentTextColor = this.m_BorderColor;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```